# Getting cast error with ObjectID despite no objectID

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I keep getting this error from this code and have no idea why {"Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"confirmed\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Order\""}

As you can see I am not even using the objectID in this query... I dont know why it is returning this

```
router.get("/orders/confirmed", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const confirmedOrders = await Order.find({ isConfirmed: false })
        res.json(confirmedOrders)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json("Error: " + err)
    }
})
```

Comment: it looks to me like there is a route above this one one thats more like "/: model/:id". Its finding that route params first. Move that route below this one in your code. That way this specific route will match first then the other one will match if other words\ids are used.

Answer (score 0):

adding my comment as answer because im 99% sure thats it. I have been there....

it looks to me like there is a route above this one one thats more like "/: model/:id". Its finding that route params first. Move that route below this one in your code. That way this specific route will match first then the other one will match if other words\ids are used.

More general note. Always sort route most specific to least specific to try to avoid this. You want /really/specific/ to come before /:something/:else because the handler with match the vars like so if they are in the wrong order... as you see in your current situation.

req.params.something === "really"
req.params.else === "specific"

Comment: Oh.... I was never aware that express worked in that way! Thank you for the help!